# Transforming black and white PNG logo to SVG path and remove background

Tags: svg, png, inkscape

I have a black and white logo as a PNG. Now, I need to use it in Inkspace to add some text and make an svg out of it. I had a satisfying result but turns out the logo has a white background.
I had a look at the svg code and found out the image wasn't represented as a path but as an `<image>`.

What i need is to transform the png image into a svg path. And make sure that there is no background. What is the easiest way to do that?

I'm not familiar at all with image manipualtion programs. I have GIMP and Inkscape installed. But i've almost never used them, so detailed steps would be appreciated.

Comment: For future similar questions (related to design) Please post them on GDSE instead: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Inkscape path tracing feature to convert it to vectors. Select your image and then select `Path -> Trace Bitmap`.  This should automatically trace the image leaving you with a set of one or more paths.

Depending on your image, you may get mixed results.  In that case you can use the path editing tools to cleanup the trace. Or use those tools to recreate the image manually from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

First go to this website https://www.remove.bg/upload
To remove the background after saving the image, go to Inkscape, fill bounded areas, choose the desired color and change the color of the image, then you will have an svg image